# How to choose between 「いれる」 and 「はいれる」？

Tags: verbs, ambiguity

The questions is how to choose between 「いれる」 and 「はいれる」.

As far as I know, the same kanji is used for both (入れる).
How can one make the distinction when reading a text?

Comment: The unsurprising answer is “by context.”

Comment: related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3807/%E5%85%A5%E3%82%89%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-versus-%E5%85%A5%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-in-a-jlpt-question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You say X **に** [入]{はい}れる, but X **を** [入]{い}れる.

The answer to these type of questions always seems to be the same, but you need the context to decide on a reading for a particular 漢字. There are many examples for when the reading of a 漢字 is dependent on the context, and the word pair you quote is one of the easier ones to guess, because [入]{はい}れる is an intransitive verb and [入]{い}れる is a transitive verb and there is a definite answer and a definite way to find out (i.e. check whether the sentence has a direct object marked with を and you know it has to be [入]{い}れる).

Comment: I worked this one out but I've been struggling with why 立ち入り禁止 is「いり」not 「はいり」....

Comment: Tx. That is good to know. I have been considering a question on topic but was going to look into it more first. Possibly the OP should be on the difference between　the intransitives いる and はいる　with reference to 入り口 and  気に入る（いる）.

Comment: @user1205935, got any support for your reading of 立ち入った? I have never heard this read in any other way than たちいった.