# 手に入る how to know proper reading

Tags: spoken-language

I have noticed that 手に入る can be read in two ways: `te ni hairu` or `te ni iru`

[Jisho accepts only the first option](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%89%8B%E3%81%AB%E5%85%A5%E3%82%8B)

But most (phonetic) keyboards allow to write it using the second form and I have an impression that I have heard it somewhere in spoken language but cannot recall proper reference.

Is the second one some kind of mistake? Or is it correct or is mainly in use in other (I mean non-Tokyo) dialect?

If it is correct, how to know which form to use when reading written language?

Comment: I have just found: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/36926/reading-of-%E5%85%A5%E3%82%8B-%E3%81%AF%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B-vs-%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B
But id doesn't mention about this particular example.

Comment: `I have heard it somewhere in spoken language` -- Is it possible that you misheard transitive 「手に[入]{い}れる」? We normally use transitive 手に[入]{い}れる and intransitive 手に[入]{はい}る in contemporary Japanese

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, 手に入る is read "te ni hairu". 入る was read いる in olden days, but is generally read はいる now. The reading 手に入{い}る is not common. This is the first time I have seen it. A reading 入{い}れる is common.

When 入る is a subsidiary verb like 消え入る, 寝入る and in a idiom like 飛んで火に入る夏の虫, it is read いる.

There are words where 入る is read as both いる and はいる, like 入り口.

Source: https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q103071965