# what the different te and tte?

Tags: grammar, て-form

hello minasan konnichiwa,
what the different te and tte?
what te = ( e ru and i ru) or to another?
and  tte =(a, o , u ru)?

because some word i can fine like hairu ( to come in ) become haitte, why not haite?

thanks, arigatoo

Comment: Yeah te and tte depend on the verb type but for the hairu thing there's this to explain that https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/36926/reading-of-%e5%85%a5%e3%82%8b-%e3%81%af%e3%81%84%e3%82%8b-vs-%e3%81%84%e3%82%8b, it has two different readings that fall into 2 different verb categories

Answer (score 1):

Verbs conjugate pretty cleanly depending on their type, as [explained in Wikipedia for the te-form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_verb_conjugation#te_form). E.g. all godan verbs ending in -る (e.g. 入る) become -って (入って).